# Ssmtp sending via gmail, but gmail complains "Delivery to the following recipend failed"

Tags: gmail, smtp

I configured `ssmtp` on my ubuntu machine according to many sources on the net. My ssmtp.conf is:

```
root=my_email@gmail.com
mailhub=smtp.gmail.com:587
rewriteDomain=eurybiades
hostname=
UseTLS=Yes
UseSTARTTLS=Yes
AuthUser=my_email
AuthPass=****
FromLineOverride=YES
```

and revaliases:

```
root:my_email@gmail.com:smtp.gmail.com:587
root@eurybiades:my_email@gmail.com:smtp.gmail.com:587
```

Then when I try to send email to `root` by `mutt`, the email is sent, but there is also email from gmail saying:

```
Delivery to the following recipient failed permanently:

    root@eurybiades

Technical details of permanent failure:
DNS Error: Domain name not found
```

What can I do not to receive this emails from gmail?

Answer (score 1):

Please note that this email is caused by `ssmtp` trying to send you system emails via your Gmail account.

This only happens when there's an issue with the script which contains your email command.

If you fix the problem with your script (mine was access issues with `rsyncv`, for example) your system won't have any system emails to send, and Gmail won't complain about the domain not being found.

It might also be relevant that you don't have a system-side email client on your system, so the only way system messages can be sent are by `ssmtp`, through Gmail, to your system accounts, which, again, will cause these symptoms.

Answer (score 0):

Use your fully qualified domain (example.com not example) in the rewrite specification.  You may need to purchase a domain if you haven't already.

EDIT:
Drop the rewrite domain line as you don't have a valid domain.
Add a root alias of the form `root=user@example.com`.  This should be the email address you want to receive the mail.

Comment: It can't be the case. It worked before, and I didn't buy any domain. The difference is, before it was sent to "root", now it goes to "root@eurybiades".

Comment: @amorfis: Updated for case where you don't have a valid domain.